# cgroups and tc/netem: Not sure how to make them work together

Tags: linux, trafficshaping, cgroups

I've having issues wrapping myself around `cgroups` and `tc`.

I'm trying to add latency to a particular process. The code below is not working. But I have no clue what's wrong (or even what's right).

```
# Set up net_cls to make 
modprobe cls_cgroup
mount -t cgroup -o net_cls none /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls

# Create a new CGroup called 'high-latency'
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/high-latency
# All packets originating from this CG have their packers
# marked as class 1:11 / 0x1_0011
echo 0x100011 > /sys/fs/cgroup/high-latency/net_cls.classid

# Delete old rules, just in case
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root

# New root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle 1: root htb
# Class for filtered packets 1:11 == 0x10011
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:11 htb rate 100Mbps
# Apply delay to class 1:11
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:11 handle 10: netem delay 1000ms

# Don't understand this line at all! Why does tc need to know
# about 'cgroup', when net_cls is already putting them in class 1:11
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:11 protocol ip prio 10 handle 1: cgroup

# Add my process to the cgroup
echo 1234 > /sys/fs/cgroup/high-latency/tasks
```

Another interesting thing is that after running this, cat `/sys/fs/cgroup/high-latency/tasks`
prints a whole bunch of processes (all?) including pid 1.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, and more importantly - what debugging tools can I use when trying to work with tc and cgroups?

Answer (score -1):

Can't work together.
you can classify the packet by `cgroup` then need to redirect the traffic to a netem interace by `netfilter` .

Comment: Can you axplain that more precisely or add an example?